# Export as GeoPackage in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I want to export the polygon I created into a GeoPackage and save it directly to my folder:

```
exlays = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('export')
exlay = exlays[0]
exlay.selectByExpression('"GRID_CODE"==4')
fn = 'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\try.gpkg'
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(exlay,fn,'utf-8',\,driverName = 'ESRI Shapefile',onlySectedFeatures=True)

Selected_layer = iface.AddVectorLayer(fn,'','ogr')

del(writer)
```

this is the error:
[image]

Comment: A single backslash is an escape  character in Python. Either use double backslashes in your path or prefix it with an `r` to make it a raw string.

Comment: Why do you use ESRI Shapefile driver if you want to save as geopackage? And do you really have a field called GRID_CODE with value of 4? I ask because it seems you just copied from https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-shapefile-from-selected-features/ but haven't adapted it properly for your case.

Comment: i actually just copied it from the tutorial in youtube, i just tried it to check if it works for me . Im new in pyqgis . but if you could help what script should i use for exporting polygons as gpkg

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is because you have single backslashes in your path string. Single backslashes are an escape character in Python. To solve this particular error, do any of the following: use single forward-slashes, use double backslashes or prefix the string with an 'r' to make it a raw string which will treat the single backslashes as literal characters. My personal preference is double backslashes but you can please yourself.

There are some additional issues with your script which would become apparent after fixing this initial error, e.g. you are using the Shapefile driver to save a Geopackage.

Although `writeAsVectorFormat()` will still work, if you look at the API docs for [QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a0fb1b773dbe4030890a04310aff4728b) you will see it is deprecated in favour of [QgsVectorFileWriterwriteAsVectorFormatV2()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3ce5d9e1ceeda1dcf3ccefb0c97f1941), which, since version 3.20, is in turn deprecated in favour of [QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a083daead2f4250762a94de06a6ce5d51). So, if you are using a QGIS release later than 3.20 (and you should be!), then that is the method you should use.

The object returned by this method is a tuple containing some return values. The first item in this tuple is an error code corresponding to the [QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3a4405a59d8f8ac147878cae5bd9bade) enumerator; the second item will be the error message text (an empty string unless an error was encountered). So it makes sense to store this returned tuple in a variable and check it to see if the method was successful and, if not, print the error message text.

This is a fairly basic example which will save a project layer called 'export' to a geopackage called 'try.gpkg' at the specified file location, and load the saved geopackage back into the current project:

```py
# get current project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()

layers = project.mapLayersByName('export')# returns a list

if not layers:# check if layers list is empty
    print('No layer named "export" in the current project')
    
else:
    layer = layers[0]# assign the first item in the list to the layer variable
    
    # define the output path
    fn = 'C:\\Users\\CMCA\\OneDrive - Boskalis\\Documents\\Trial PyQGIS\\try.gpkg'
    
    # create save options and set some attributes e.g. driver name & encoding
    save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    save_options.driverName = "GPKG"
    save_options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
    # get transform context from the project
    transform_context = project.transformContext()
    
    # call writeAsVectorFormatV3() method, passing required arguments and
    # assign the return value to a variable
    error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer,
                                                      fn,
                                                      transform_context,
                                                      save_options)
    
    # check error code and, if not successful, print the error message text
    if error[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print("Layer successfully saved!")
        # if write operation successful, load the saved geopackage to the project
        iface.addVectorLayer(fn, 'try', 'ogr')
    else:
      print(error[1])
```

Comment: Nice. What is the difference between using QgsProject.instance().transformContext() and QgsCoordinateTransformContext() in QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3? If I want to export the new layer in the same CRS from input layer, is it ok to use only QgsCoordinateTransformContext()?